# rosmake fails to find rosbuild.cmake on fuerte

Tags: ubuntu, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, osx, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

after following the install instructions for Ubuntu 12.04 & ROS fuerte here:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu

I'm unable to build any rosbuild-based packages.  I receive the following error during "rosmake":

```
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (include):
    include could not find load file:
  
      /opt/ros/fuerte/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake
  
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (rosbuild_init):
    Unknown CMake command "rosbuild_init".
```

`rospack find rosbuild` returns:

```
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild
```

so it looks like the /share/ros is missing from all my cmake files. A bug? or am I supposed to do something special with my old CMakeLists.txt files?

I've observed this behavior under both Ubuntu 12.04 (from official debs) and Mac OSX (from source)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34296/rosmake-fails-to-find-rosbuild.cmake-on-fuerte/) by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1607 on 2012-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe something is wrong with your environment configuration. What's the value of ROS_ROOT and how do you set it? For fuerte it should be `/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2012-05-18**:
Ah ha! You nailed it. It was originally set by the setup.bash/sh scripts created by a rosws unit call added to my bashrc file. However I changed those scripts manually (even though I shouldnt)